# What's the difference between f(arguments) to f.apply(this,arguments)?

Tags: javascript, decorator

I have not been studying JavaScript for a long time and now I'm trying to implement the Decorator pattern:

```
function wrap(f, before, after){
        return function(){
            return before + f(arguments) + after;
        }
}
```

What I'm wondering about is that if we replace `f(arguments)` to `f.apply(this,arguments)` there is no obvious difference in output. 
Could you please clarify which case is preferable and why?

**UPD:**
I suppose I have understood what is the bottleneck :) 
If we decorate function with aforementioned code without arguments, everything will be ok. But if we have arguments we will have to enumerate them like `arguments[0],arguments[1]` etc. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `f(arguments)` just calls `f` and passes an *Array*-like object (containing arguments) to it, this is **not** what you'd want.
2. `f.call(this, arguments[0], arguments[1], ..)` would require you to list every argument out and it's pretty much the same as `f(arguments[0], arguments[1], ..)`, minus the function context.
3. `f.apply(this, arguments)` would call `f` and passes each argument in `arguments` as actual arguments.

Method #3 is what you'd want if you're trying to implement a wrapper function and not have to consider what arguments are being passed into `f`.

Learn more about methods for Function:

- `call()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call
- `apply()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply
- `arguments`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments

Comment: That's what I was thinking about. Thank you!