# Closure in JavaScript and running a function once

Tags: javascript, closures

The following [`function once`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-good/9781457197703/) (problem 13) will take `func` and return a function that allows `func` to be called only once.

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function once(func) {
    return function () {
        var f = func;
        func = null;
        return f.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

add_once = once(add);
add_once(3, 4)   // 7
add_once(3, 4)   // throws
```

There are two things that I don't get about this.

1. Why does writing `func = null` stop us from calling the function a second time? After saving the pointer to the function (it's all right to use the C lingo; isn't it?) in `var f = func`, I'd expect that assigning `null` to the function pointer `func` (`func` is just a function pointer; isn't it?) is irrelevant—because the (pointer to the) function is already stored in `f`. What am I missing?
2. I get that it's [necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23254512/704972) to write `f.apply(this, arguments);` rather than simply `f(arguments);` because it's one of JavaScript's idiosyncrasies. The latter would send an array, not a list of arguments, to the function. But I don't get what `this` refers to. Does it refer to the anonymous function on the second line or to `once`? And if assigning `func = null` is meant to stop the second invocation because the closure will lead to a `func` that has been nulled, why does it work the first time it's called?

I am using too many questions to give you the chance of identifying what I'm missing, not with the expectation that you'd type a long answer addressing each sub-question independently.

Comment: The way you are calling it, `this` will be the global object or `undefined` if in strict mode.

Comment: for your question 1: the mistery is keyword "var". when you define a variable with "var", that mean ignore all the same named variable value in current or parent scope and use newly assigned value for current scope. so second call of var f = func will cause f = null.

Comment: @Tolgahan: the code would work exactly the same without `var`.

Comment: @FelixKling :)) yes. you are right. But it was a great "var" description, wasn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why does writing func = null stop us from calling the function a second time?"

- when add_once is ran the first time these are the steps that are taken......

  `var f = func;` step1 - the variable f now has reference to the add function that was passed in as a parameter. func still has reference to the add function as well, so now both func and f are pointing to the same add function.

  `func = null;` step2 - now the func points to null and no longer references the add function. But the vairable f still has reference to the add function.

  `return f.apply(this,arguments);` step3 - since f still references the add function we can pass that function the arguments array and call it immediately. apply immediately calls the add function with the arguments given. We then return the result. 'this' is binded to whatever f is referencing, in this case it is the add function. A good trick to remember is that 'this' is going to be binded to whatever is to the left of the '.' at the call site aka where the function is called. Doesn't really matter in this case though. You could also put null in its place and it would work just fine.
- when add_once is ran a second time these are the new steps taken....

  `var f = func;` step1 - we now point f to whatever value func is referencing. func is still referencing null since we pointed func to null the first time the function was ran. Now f and func are both pointing at null.

  `func = null;` step2 - we point the func variable/parameter to null again. func already was pointing to null, so now func is definitely pointing to null.

  `return f.apply(this,arguments);` step3 - here f is still pointing to null. you obviously can not call null, as null is not a function. Here is where the error is thrown.

Hope this helps. A thing I like to remember is that a variable does not store anything, it references a value. I like to think of a variable as pointing to a value. You can have many variables pointing to the same value. Reassigning a variable just points that variable to a new value.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, you aren't calling `once` again a second time so that when you see `func` used inside the returned function, **it is no longer a pointer** to whatever was passed into `once` because the returned function has modified the value (because the returned function was already called previously) referred to by the variable named `func` inside the closure provided by `once`, by saying `func = null`. After being called the first time, the value returned inside the return function when you ask for the value of `func` has changed from the original value passed into `once` to `null`.

**EDIT**

After reading what I just wrote, although it makes sense to me, I can't blame you if it doesn't help you :S

**EDIT #2**

The second part of your question - what is `this` referring to. It completely depends on how you call the function returned by `once`. See **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)*** question

*pun intended

Comment: You nailed it (my misunderstanding) with the first few words, but then you confused the heck out of me with the rest. I only figured out what was going on after reading Dillon's answer, so I'll check-mark his answer and +1 yours.